# ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-_iic033m

Tags: python, installation, pyautogui

> ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in
> C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-_iic033m
> when I install pyautogui, the python version on my computer is python 3.10.11

```
> pip install pyautogui 
Collecting pyautogui   Using cached
> PyAutoGUI-0.9.54.tar.gz (61 kB)   Installing build dependencies ...
> done   Getting requirements to build wheel ... done   Preparing
> metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done Collecting pymsgbox (from
> pyautogui)   Using cached PyMsgBox-1.0.9.tar.gz (18 kB)   Installing
> build dependencies ... done   Getting requirements to build wheel ...
> done   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done Collecting
> pytweening>=1.0.4 (from pyautogui)   Using cached
> pytweening-1.0.7.tar.gz (168 kB)   Preparing metadata (setup.py) ...
> done ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in
> C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-oydd_5o0
```